# PHP Rewrite Rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The actually URL which my app uses is:

```
http://site.com/search.php?search=iPhone
```

but I would like it to be possible to achieve the same with

```
http://site.com/iPhone
```

I have no experience of rewrite rules, how can I set this up?

The solution has worked but the new URL is displayed in the address bar. I thought it would have been possible to set this up so that it appears as though the page location is

`http://site.com/iPhone`

without changing to display

```
http://site.com/search.php?search=iPhone
```

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a file called .htaccess in the root of your website and put this in it.

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^(.*) search.php?search=$1 [R]
```

Should do the trick.

I would suggest however that you make it a bit more specific, so maybe require the user of a search directory in your url.  eg instead of mysite.com/IPhone  use mysite.com/search/IPhone which would work like

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^search/(.*) search.php?search=$1 [R]
```

This makes it easier to have normal pages that arnt redirected, such as about us or a basic homepage.

As Chris says, this is not PHP but Apache that does this, and whether it works can depend on your hosting setup.

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify something like this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /(.*) /search.php?search=$1
```

Check also:

- [mod_rewrite: A Beginner's Guide to URL Rewriting](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting/)
- [Module mod_rewrite, URL Rewriting Engine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Why does your regex only try to match numbers? Just curious since his example used "iPhone", not a number.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite rules aren't part of PHP as far as I'm aware, but Apache (specifically `mod_rewrite`) or whatever server you're using. For Apache, you need on the server to have a file called `.htaccess`, and in it put something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /index.php?search=$1
```

`^(\w+)/?$` is a regular expression - it matches any word of 1 or more characters, followed by a `/` maybe. So it changes `site.com/iPhone` into `site.com/index.php?search=iPhone`. Sound about right?