# How to hide get variables of more than one link in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have a site with many links that send a get request, how can I hide the variables. Eg, `www.mysite.com/home.php?id=name` to `www.mysite.com/name` and second link `www.mysite.com/page.php?id=1` to `www.mysite.com/1`
I was able to achieve to hide the first link using htaccess, but the previous links, I couldn't. All issues address on this sites were based on single link.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Rewrite Rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559186/php-rewrite-rules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To differentiate between those 2 issues I think you can catch all numbers first and then check `\w+` character later.

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# skip all files and redirectories from rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ page.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ home.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for coming to my rescue.  I tried to add more variables to the links, say page.php?I'd=1&control=new how can I change the code. Thanks once again. Am very new in htaccess

Comment: You can add: `RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(\w+)/??$ page.php?id=$1&control=$2 [L,QSA]`

Comment: I have tried it but got a 404 error, that's objet not found

Comment: See it is difficult to add support to new question from comments section. Better to create a new question with all the information so that I can suggest better answer.