# rewrite-dynamic-url using php and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mysqli

i have this URL

```
/products_ab.php?id=1
```

and i want this URL

```
/Brass-Window-Stay.html
```

when i click on `/products_ab.php?id=1` link and then URL changes to Brass-Window-Stay.html dynamically not statically.

I have database field for this ID and Name also.

Can you please give some hyperlink example that (if i get data from database it is possible to show in SEO friendly url)? I'm new please help...
I have visited similar question but didn't get any answer.
A little help would be a great help!

**UPDATE**

```
<ul>
<?php
$rec = mysqli_query($con,"select * from category");
while ($arr = mysqli_fetch_array($rec)) {
echo "<li><a href='products.php?id=" . $arr[0] . "'>" . $arr[1] . "</a></li>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

Like how can i use above code to generate dynamic link

Comment: Please do some research on htaccess and RewriteRule with regular expressions.

Comment: i have tried but failed to develop dynamic link generation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559186/php-rewrite-rules

Comment: @Dharmang dear i said Dynamic not static , this means i have database i need to call name by id from database dynamically

Comment: just use little bit logic .take new field url in database save the title in that with replacing space by "-". then use htacces rule

Comment: @sasikanth a piece of code or example will be very good to me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^product\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /product.php?product=$1 [L]
```

And following in product.php for example

```
<?php

print_r($_GET);
```

Now once you visit domain.com/test-product.html OR domain.com/test-product-1.html OR domain.com/test-product-2.html etc.

you will get output like:

```
Array ( [product] => test-product.html )
```

Now you can use this product variable and query database to dynamically generate page.

It seems like I am doing coding for you :)

Check this good reference: http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

Comment: Thanks i ll try this and let u know what happens :)