# API RewriteRules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I´m trying to build a API for an Webproject. 
The Folderstructure is the following:

```
/api
  -/v1
     - .htaccess
     -/question
         -all.php
```

Now I´m trying to build a URL-Rewrite for the following case.
I want to enter this URL:
http://localhost/api/v1/question/all/2003

and get to
http://localhost/api/v1/question/all.php?questionid=2003

I build this Rewrite Rule but only get a 404 Error.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^all/([0-9]+) all.php?questionid=$1 [NC, L]
```

Can some one tell me if this RewriteRule is correct? Or tell me the correct way.

Comment: might this be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/559192/4610605

Comment: Your .htaccess is in the `v1` folder, so at the very least you should include `question` in the first argument of `RewriteRule`. Other than that I find that .htaccess files work oddly when not in the DocumentRoot of your website, especially if you have multiple in the path to the resource.